# make grid view with java graphics

Tags: java, list, gridview, grid, user-experience

I make personal project with java.

using graphics library, so I don't use awt grid, tab etc.

my idea is below with images.

only use keyboard arrow keys and enter key. 
moving list with arrow keys, get information with enter key.

A list has a tab minimum 3.

[image]
only access item1 of tab1. and  move available only right. because tab1 is first.

User can see visible area.

[image]
If user pressed right arrow key. then all of item move left.

and tab4 is invisible state to visible state.

and focus moves  item1 of tab1 to tab1 of tab2

[image]
user show number of tabs is three.

[image]

this is one of item list

use press up key and down key. 
item list will be movable.

---

tihs is my idea. 
I use only java graphics library.
How I design my idea?

Comment: What are the items?  How are they rendered?

Comment: tabs and items has text or image etc..

Comment: Are the renderer through the `Graphics` API? Are the components? Are the separate entities (capable of rendering themselves) or are they self contained (rendered by the main control)?

Comment: using Graphics API and each items are contains another Graphics items